# Mac OS : Show custom column in finder for files like name, size etc.

Tags: swift, macos, filesystems, kernel, finder

I want to add a custom column in finder like name, size, type etc without kernel.

Is there any way in programming language for Mac OS (C/C++/ObjectiveC/Swift) without going to kernel.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you **don't want** to program in the kernel, why use "kernel" tag?

Answer (score 3):

No. There is no way to do this, *period* -- kernel extensions cannot add features to the Finder.

The only interface for displaying additional information in the Finder is the [FinderSync](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/findersync) framework, which is intended for use by applications like Dropbox for displaying custom badges, shortcut menu items, and/or toolbar icons while viewing specific directories.

Comment: Yes, FinderSync can do these things but how to add custom column in finder, any example?

Comment: As I said, **there is no way to do this**. End of story. Not possible.